# Reading text files c++

Tags: c++, class, text-files, istream

i am new to c++ and i'm try to write a code that reads integers of a text file and saves each integer in different variables line by line. 
I am having problems with the syntax and how to arrange the code. Basically the text file contains 4 integers per line which values are to be read to the a class planet's coordinates and id as shown below. I know the code beloe is incomplete  but this is the first time im programming with c++ and need help. please you do not need to explain this using planets or anything. I just need a general understanding

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>



using namespace std;

class planet{
    public :
    float x_coordinates;
    float y_coordinates;
    float z_coordinates;
    int id;
};




planet*generate_planet(istream &fin)
{
    planet *x= new planet;
    fin >> x->id >> x->x_coordinates >> x->y_coordinates >> x->z_coordinates;

    return (x);
}
void report_planet( planet &p)
{

 cout<<"planet "<<p.id<<" has coordinates (" << p.x_coordinates<<","<<       p.y_coordinates<<","<< p.z_coordinates<<")"<<endl;
}
int main()
{
planet p;
planet *x;
ifstream fin("route.txt");
generate_planet(fin);
report_planet(*x);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some issues: you don't save the returned planet* from generate_planet to pass to report_planet(). You leak this memory. Then you pass an ofstream to report_planet() instead of whatever generate_planet() returns.

Answer (score 3):

You have some errors in your code.

Note that in this line:
`fin>>x->id>>x->x_coordinates>>x->y_coordinates>>x->y_coordinates;` You write twice to `x->y_coordinate` instead of `x->z_coordinate`.

Also, your `void report_planet(planet &p)` function receives `planet &` as argument, but you pass it `fin` which is of time `ofstream`

Another thing is you're trying to read a file, not write to one, hence the use of `ofstream` is wrong, you should use `ifstream` instead.

Does your code even compile?

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the observations, It compiled but its not running properly, i will add the corrections u stated

Comment: there are some more errors and design issues in here. You should delete everything you created with new.Also i suggest that "create_planet" should be a constructor type for your planet class and "report_planaet" a member function. Please look at some basics of object orientation in C++. Classes are no structs.

Comment: Also, if this answer helped you, please consider an up-vote accepting it.